# How do I create an iPhone app to take a picture and send it back to an Oracle database?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, oracle, photo

I'm trying to create a program that you can take a photo with your camera, and send it back, where it will then be attached as a field into an Oracle database. An existing app that this is similar to (if I'm not explaining it clearly enough) would be bank apps that allow you to photograph the front and back of your checks, then send them off to a different location to be processed.

From my understanding, I would need some sort of middleware and not access the database directly with the pictures taken, but I'm just trying to get the project off the ground at the moment.

So, my immediate questions are:

1. What sort of base project template would be the best to use for this kind of app?
2. What sort of code is required to send a file from one location to another? (I'm mainly used to these scenarios in .NET languages, not in xCode)

Answer (score 2):

Expose an `HTTP` based service (and that can be written in any language and run on any platform e.g. `GNU/Linux`).

The app itself would be native `iOS`, and you can certainly consume web-services.

The server itself is just your basic CRUD system backed by a persistent store, in your case an RDBMS.

```
[iOS] <-----/net:HTTP/---->[server]<==/LINQ/==>[RDBMS]
```